# Bend a UIView's frame

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, drawing

Is it possible to bend a UIView or rectangle into a curve?

Edit: What I'd like is a UIProgressView to be bent in the shape of an arc/ or a sun. Right now its in the form of a rectangle (default). When the progress is animated it'd be great to see it animating over a curve(rather than a horizontal line like what happens when its rectangular).

So more specifically, can I take a UIProgressView and bend it using code? Bent in the way the attached image is bent..

Here's an example:
[image: Bent rectangle]

Comment: Your question is too vague to be answerable. You posted a picture of a small arc. What is the total effect you're after? Do you want an animation, or a static appearance? And what image do you want to bend? The outline of a rectangle? An image view? Something else? Please be more specific.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and
[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).